# Convert 0 to -150V DC to 0 to 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, negative

I have a signal that gives spikes up to negative 150V. I need to be able to determine these spikes using MCU that can sens 0 to 3.3V.
How can i adjust a signal so that it doesnt fry my MCU. It should be a power friendly method.

Thanks!

[image: Here is the measurement of the spike on oscilloscope]

Comment: Do you need to galvanically isolate the MCU from the spike source?

Comment: Without the signal shape (particularly including the time axis) it's rather difficult to give a reliable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work if the source of your pulse has a reasonably
low impedance. The MCU input would preferably have a Schmitt trigger input type, or add a ST buffer before the input. If the load on your 3.3V supply is at least 1.5mA it will be able to handle +150V/-500V transients (limited in the negative direction by the resistor surge rating and voltage rating). Transition (1.65V) is at about -33V, so the pulse at the MCU should be around 150usec.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0NYhs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

1:

Use an optocoupler. The series resistor for the optocoupler diode should be 150/Ion.
Ion is the turn-on current of the optocoupler.
Make sure that the optocoupler can handle higher current if the spike hits an absolute voltage higher than 150V. Otherwise, go for higher resistance and take the highest spike level.

Watch out for the polarity; -150V goes to the cathode of the optocoupler diode and GND goes to the anode with resistance in series.

Make sure that there is no +ve peak.
Otherwise, you need to protect the optocoupler's diode from reverse voltage with a simple diode in series with breakdown voltage higher than experienced in the worst case.

On the transistor side of the optocoupler, connect the collector to GND and emitter to the GPIO of the MCU. Enable the GPIO's pull-up if possible. Otherwise, you need an external pull-up resistor (1k to 10k).

Make sure that the GPIO is always input.
To be safe, place a resistor between emitter and the GPIO.

DO NOT connect the GND of high voltage side to the GND of MCU. You need isolation and that is why optocoupler is there.

2:

Use a voltage divider but you will not get any isolation.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a very fast rise pulse.  I would recommend just AC coupling it with a series capacitor, perhaps 0.1 uF, a pull-up resistor since you're interested in the falling edge, and a pair of clamp diodes to +3.3v and GND.